# Eclipse - Maven Dependencies missing

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, dependencies

I'm here to get some solutions.
I was about to set a development environment.
I downloaded Eclipse ,which is Kepler, and downloaded some projects from SVN.

There is the problem in Maven Dependencies of Java Build Path.
Maven dependencies has several jar files and some folders.
Some project gets correct but a project gets everything as jar although something shouldn't be a jar file.
I would like to make it as folder but I don't know how to do that.

I'm gonna appreciate if you guys give me the answer or any tip.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Self solution :
Eclipse - Window - preferences - Maven - User Settings - Update Settings button click
It solved the problem.